# How to use root option in babel-plugin-module-resolver?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-plugin

I'm trying to use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) in a react-native app. When I use plugin config like this in `babel.config.js` it works perfectly.

```
plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
          utils: './src/utils',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

But the problem is that I have to write ./src in every alias path. So I tried to use `root` option. Here's the code I tried

```
plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: './src', // I also tried ['./src']
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
          utils: 'utils', // already tried '/utils' and './utils'
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

But that didn't worked for me and I get this error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module '../../../utils/Themes' from 'src/components/shared/Container.js':
```

So what's the correct way to use `root` option?

Comment: What are you using for your bundler? Webpack?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found a solution that doesn't really fix the problem but makes it works.

I'm using typescript, and babel to compile it.

My files structure is something like this:

```
|-dist
|-src
  |-db
     |-connect
        |-index.ts
  |-index.ts
|-.babelrc
|-etc...
```

When babel compiles my code, the import of `db/connect` in `src/index.ts`, go from this:

```
import ... from "db/connect"
```

to this:

```
var _connect = require("../db/connect");
```

and should be like this:

```
var _connect = require("./db/connect");
```

How you can see, babel backs one folder, and no matter what I try, this still missing the require path.

So, to resolve this, I simply add `/dist` to the paths in `.babelrc`

before:

```sh
[
   "module-resolver",
      {
         "root": ["./"], # or ["src"] or "src" or ["./src"] or "./src" or any way you can imagine
         "alias": {
            "db": "./db",
         }
      }
   }
]
```

after:

```
[
   "module-resolver",
      {
         "alias": {
            "db": "./dist/db",
         }
      }
   }
]
```

And as you said, the `root` doesn't affect the require path, so I just removed it.

This doesn't fix the problem, but makes it work.

Hope it helps, good luck! :)

Comment: Exactly, I couldn't figure out what `root` was doing either. Would like to know. But I got it to work via `alias` as shown here.

Answer (score 0):

check in file bable.config.js and remove plugin module-resolver, root
It help for me